# Python unittest on PyCharm sometimes passes without changing any code in SUT

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest

The problem is the first of it's kind which I have come across. I have a class and the corresponding unit test. The test passes/fails randomly without any change on the class under test. I mean I press **shift+F10** and immediately press it again. One passes the other one fails.

This is the class (it looks kinda dirty, though. Forgive me)

```
class XmlSerializer:

    def __init__(self, int_repr = 'int', str_repr = 'str'):
        """@int_repr: integer type representation (default: 'int')
        @str_repr : string type representation (default: 'str')"""
        self.xml_result = []
        self.__int_repr = int_repr
        self.__str_repr = str_repr

    def serialize(self, element):
        self.xml_result = []
        self.__recurse2(element, indent='')
        return ''.join(self.xml_result)

    def __recurse2(self, element, indent):
        if isinstance(element, int):
            self.xml_result += indent + '\t<' + self.__int_repr + '>' + str(element) + '</' + self.__int_repr + '>\n'
        if isinstance(element, str):
            self.xml_result += indent + '\t<' + self.__str_repr + '>' + str(element) + '</' + self.__str_repr + '>\n'
        elif type(element) in [type(list()), type(tuple()), type(dict())]:
            for el in element:
                self.__recurse2(el, indent + '\t')
        else:
            try: # Attribute names are printed only here
                attrs = vars(element)
                self.xml_result += indent + '<' + element.__class__.__name__ + '>\n'
                for attr in attrs:
                    self.xml_result += indent + '\t'  + '<'+ attr +'>\n'
                    self.__recurse2(attrs[attr], indent + '\t')
                    self.xml_result += indent + '\t'  + '</'+ attr +'>\n'
                self.xml_result += indent + '</' + element.__class__.__name__ + '>\n'
            except Exception as ex:
                pass
```

And here is the Test Class (the whole content of the file)

```
import unittest
from string_and_regex.xml_stuff import XmlSerializer


class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Sam"
        self.age = 26


class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'sample object'
        self.people = [Person(), Person()]


group_serialized = '<Group>\n' \
                   '\t<name>\n' \
                   '\t\t<str>sample object</str>\n' \
                   '\t</name>\n' \
                   '\t<people>\n' \
                   '\t\t<Person>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t<name>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t\t<str>Sam</str>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t</name>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t<age>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t\t<int>26</int>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t</age>\n' \
                   '\t\t</Person>\n' \
                   '\t\t<Person>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t<name>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t\t<str>Sam</str>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t</name>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t<age>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t\t<int>26</int>\n' \
                   '\t\t\t</age>\n' \
                   '\t\t</Person>\n' \
                   '\t</people>\n' \
                    "</Group>\n"


class TestXmlSerializer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_serialize(self):
        serializer = XmlSerializer()
        xml_result = serializer.serialize(Group())
        self.assertEquals(group_serialized, xml_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(Also forgive me for the test case I come up with, I know)

Comment: You're iterating over `vars(element)`. Are you aware that dicts do not have a predictable iteration order? Also, `type(list())` is just `list`, `type(dict())` is just `dict`, and `type(tuple())` is just `tuple`.

Comment: @user2357112 Even though it is the same dictionary every time?

Comment: It's not the same dict every time. The dicts might have equivalent contents, but equivalent dicts can have different iteration orders. The only guarantee is that if you iterate over a dict, and then iterate over that specific dict again without adding or removing keys, you'll get the same order.

Comment: @user2357112 One final question, though. On the python console **vars(group)** returns always the same dictionary with same order? (where group is an instance of Group)

Comment: @user2357112 However, I tested the code inside the script and yes that happens. You are definitely right. Can you post this as an answer, please?  Maybe some people can fall for this like I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicts have no predictable iteration order. When you iterate over `vars(element)`:

```
attrs = vars(element)
self.xml_result += indent + '<' + element.__class__.__name__ + '>\n'
for attr in attrs:
```

Each run of your test will iterate in its own arbitrary order. This might be fairly consistent, or randomized, or it might behave in pretty much any way, depending on specifics of the interpreter implementation and settings. You're probably on Python 3, in which string hash codes are randomized.

Don't depend on dict iteration order.